# Can't reset cache in Next.js with RTK query

Tags: javascript, next.js, react-redux, server-side-rendering, rtk-query

I am using Next.js with `next-redux-wrapper` and RTK Query. My app is making external API calls on server side. I've implemented that request in this way:

```js
CompaniesPage.getInitialProps = initialPagePropsWithCompanies;

// ---
import { createWrapper } from 'next-redux-wrapper';

const wrapper = createWrapper<ReturnType<typeof makeStore>>(makeStore);
export const initialPagePropsWithCompanies = wrapper.getInitialPageProps((store: AppStore) => async () => {
  store.dispatch(api.endpoints.getHomePage.initiate());
  await Promise.all(store.dispatch(api.util.getRunningQueriesThunk()));
  return { props: {} };
});
```

The problem is that response is cached in Next.js somewhere. And I can't understand how to disable it, or reduce life time.

1. I have `export const revalidate = 5;` on my page.
2. I've added `cache: 'no-store'` to `fetchBaseQuery` config:

```js
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROTOCOL || 'https://'}${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL}/api`,
    headers: {
      'x-telegram-query': typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window.Telegram.WebApp.initData : '',
    },
    cache: 'no-store',
  }),
```

3. I've also tried to add `next: { revalidate: 5 }` to `fetchBaseQuery` config.

Nothing helps . Have no ideas. Anybody could give suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this. **forceRefetch**

```
export const revalidate = 0;

const HomePage = async () => {
  const { data } = await store.dispatch(
    articlesApi.endpoints.getArticles.initiate(
      { id: 2 },
      {
        forceRefetch: true,
      }
    )
  );
  return (
    <div></div>
  );
};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).